# How to add Different type of TextSize inside a button in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add a button which have Two Text with different TextSize.
here is the sample
[image]

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

rather than a button why don't you make it something like a boxview, add your text as labels with different text sizes, then give the box a tap gesture?

add this in OnAppearing

```
var my_tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
my_tap.Tapped += (s, e) =>
     {
         // do your thing;
      };
YourBoxView.GestureRecognizers.Add(connect_tap);
```

Or a StackLayout:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="buttonStack" BackgroudColor="Blue">
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="YourCode"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label FontSize="Large">your text</Label>
    <Label FontSize="Small">your other text</Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Yes I can do it but TapGestureRecognizer is not have any select effect

Comment: what do you mean, 'not any select effect', what is it you need to do?

Comment: TapGestureRecognizer not give any effect as a button touch effects

Comment: instead of a box try a stacklayout, probably within a grid and add the gesture in XAML, i'll put it in the answer