# Binding FontSize Not working Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

XAML:

```
<Button Text="Submit" FontSize="{Binding BtnFontSize,Mode=Twoway}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
string _btnFontSize;
        public string BtnFontSize
        {
            get { return _saveBtnFontSize; }
            set
            {
                _saveBtnFontSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

while setting first time its works = > `BtnFontSize="Large"`
after it not working => `BtnFontSize="Small"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following changes and it should work:

Remove two-way binding as it is not needed

```
<Button Text="Submit" FontSize="{Binding BtnFontSize}"/>
```

In the OnPropertyChanged method pass the property name

```
 private double _btnFontSize;
 public double BtnFontSize
    {
        get { return _saveBtnFontSize; }
        set
        {
            _saveBtnFontSize = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BtnFontSize));
        }
    }
```

And to get the default xamarin forms label font sizes you will use the NamedSize enum:

which should be something like below for eg to set the size to Medium you will do the following

```
BtnFontSize= Device.GetNamedSize (NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
```

Where `typeof(Label)` signifies the control you are using so when you need to set button font size you will pass button here

Comment: Do you know how to add different types of text size in a single button?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650801/how-to-add-different-type-of-textsize-inside-a-button-in-xamarin-forms/54650935?noredirect=1#comment96093841_54650935

Comment: why do you plan on adding them in a single button(curious)

Comment: I want to show the amount with small size so that it looks well

Comment: Why not use a layout and do that i mean i would do it like that ?

Comment: I can create this using boxview but I want that inside the button :(

Comment: That is what I am curious about, that why a button exactly! is there a specific reason? like the animation or something like that?

Comment: Actualy Button is very flexible while using boxView GestureRecognizer

Comment: I can guide you on making a custom control of you want

Comment: how to create this wiuth custom control?

Comment: The only issue you have with using a BoxView is that you cannot directly give it a command right?

Comment: No.only issue is that,I want the effect of button touch.

Comment: we can work together to come up with a custom control if you want

Comment: Ok,I agree to create custom control